# Separating two lists within single object using ui.chart.array.values

Tags: google-earth-engine

I have the code below, however, when I try to plot my chart, I am getting one error message. I believe this is related to the fact that within my object `VIIR2014List` I have two lists, one for average radiance, another for coordinates.

How can I get rid of this error message?

```
////////////////------------------------------------------------ VIIRS DATA
var VIIRS = ee.ImageCollection("NOAA/VIIRS/DNB/MONTHLY_V1/VCMSLCFG");
VIIRS = VIIRS.select('avg_rad');

var latLon = ee.Image.pixelLonLat().select('longitude');

var VIIRS2014 = VIIRS.filterDate('2014-1-1','2015-1-1').mean().addBands(latLon);
var VIIRS2019 = VIIRS.filterDate('2019-1-1','2020-1-1').mean().addBands(latLon);

var VIIR2014List = VIIRS2014.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.toList(),
  geometry: mydiagonal,
  scale: 1000,
  maxPixels: 1e9
});

print (VIIR2014List, "Lists 2014"); /// 2014

var VIIR2019List = VIIRS2019.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.toList(),
  geometry: mydiagonal,
  scale: 1000,
  maxPixels: 1e9
});

print (VIIR2019List, "Lists 2019"); /// 2019
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The returned object is an `ee.Dictionary()`. Get the single list values from the dictionary and plot these as follows:

```
// subset the lists
var lon = ee.List(VIIR2014List.get('longitude'))
var avgRad = ee.List(VIIR2014List.get('avg_rad'))
var chart = ui.Chart.array.values(avgRad, 0, lon )
```

See [full link](https://code.earthengine.google.com/b0b4b1989ed80766d29afb1d4760995e)